# Downloading google earth roads?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, google-earth, brazil

I am trying to find a good source of roads data, the idea is mapping an entire state of a country in Brazil, so what I need is really large and good data.

Can I get all the roads of Google Earth in a specified area in a easy way so I can used it in ArcGIS?

If that is not possible, what source instead of OpenStreetMap can I use to do that task?

(OpenStreetMap has really good data, but there are some parts that are missing, some parts are really badly plotted and etc, and because of that it would take a long to adjust everything.

Comment: It is not possible to get the roads from Google. THere may be some datasets from Brazil that can be downloaded. Consider asking this question on the Open Data site. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will try to look there.